# Brief editor availability

Tags: editor, brief-bookmarks

In the 1990's I used a wonderful editor called [Brief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_%28text_editor%29). But recently I am using the Brief emulator mode inside the Visual Studio editor and I am not satisfied.

The one main advantage of the Brief editor was, it did not have any scroll bars, and menu items, and I could use my screen fully. And the window separator was also very slim.

My question:
Those guys/gals who used to be fans of Brief, after the DOS version died, which editor resembles the DOS version of Brief better?

Note: This problem is pronounced when I am editing in Windows. And I have some how learnt to use vi in Linux.

Comment: For over 17+ years I've been using Emacs plus my own **extended Brief emulator** as my main editor. It's now mature and available in _GNU Emacs Lisp Package Archive_ [ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/brief.html). Actually, since I started using Emacs 17+ years ago I never use any other editor mode; even today I am still not able to use Emacs native key mappings. Hope this helps if anyone is still looking for a free Brief editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *My question: Those guys/gals who used to be fans of Brief, after the DOS version died, which editor resembles the DOS version of Brief better?*

The [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com/) has a Brief emulation mode, but as the author of Zeus, I might be a little biased.

On the other hand, some *Zeus users* think [Zeus is a better Brief](http://www.zeusedit.com/awards.html) than *Brief*.

Comment: jussig, thanks for the link, it seems that the editor is not free ~~~ anyway I will try it, thanks again ~~

Comment: PS: To enable the Brief keyboard in Zeus use the Options, Editor Options menu and go to the keyboard mapping section.

There are two Brief modes, regular (i.e. Brief) and extended (i.e. BriefEx). The extended mode is effectively Brief + Windows shortcuts.

Comment: Nice emulation. The feel is a lot like the original Brief editor.

Comment: Nice snappy editor and the Brief emulation is great :)

Comment: At Eur 106 / US $ 120 after tax, this is quite pricey. In the 7 years since this answer was posted, we now have http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and I woudl recommend anyone looking for a Brief editor to ask there for a free one.

Comment: For $120 you get unlimited free support and software that never expires, meaning you can use the software for years to come, as many long time Zeus user still do. Over that same period you would spend very much more on your daily cup of coffee.

Comment: Also at $US 120 you are paying a lot of VAT (i.e. tax) as the actual price is only $US 90 before tax.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion: If you already know Vi (or Vim) why don't you use that on Windows as well? The Windows version of Vim is excellent. There's a Vim plugin (ViEmu) for Visual Studio, so you can use Vim all over the place. I find it very useful to be able to use the same editing commands for all my tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I still drop into my DOS-BRIEF once in a while just for the sheer nostalgia of it :-)

I use EMACS now. The commands require more keystrokes but I have pretty much everything in it that BRIEF gave me. With the right amount of configuration, EMACS stays out of your way too.

If you loved working with BRIEF, I think you will like EMACS. There's something about the philosophy behind the two editors that appeals to me - the amount of thought that has gone into each feature, the customizability, the sheer power.

BRIEF stuff you will find in EMACS, and not in many other editors:
 1. Column block cut/copy/paste
 2. Filename completion / folder listing without opening a dialog / window
 3. Intuitive navigation
 4. Way more text manipulation stuff
 5. In-editor compilation and debugging (although this is usually a bit more painful to get  working right)
 6. Split buffers
 7. Buffer list
 8. Get stuff done with the keyboard more, and depend on the mouse less
 9. Powerful macros
10. Powerful regular-expression search / replace, speed search
11. Powerful scripting language with compilation
And a whole lot more...

You can even hide the scrollbars :-)

The one thing you will likely miss is Num-key minus and del keys for cut / delete, ins for paste. (If you use a notebook, this won't be a problem anyway since getting at these keys on a notebook would be way more difficult than EMACS' default key bindings). And you could configure EMACS key-bindings to handle this if you really want to. I've used scripting to get line mark/cut in a single operation like BRIEF and unlike EMACS' default behavior which is you mark the line with one command and then cut it with another.

One word of warning though. With BRIEF you could start being productive in a week. EMACS needs way lot more work than that but I've found it worth it.

The other key thing I like about EMACS is that it is available on pretty much every operating system out there. I use a MacBook with Mac OS X and Windows XP. I also occasionally use Ubuntu Linux. EMACS is available everywhere and I don't have to stop and think about anything when switching between these OS'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about CRiSP/BRIEF mode in Emacs? Just try M-x crisp-mode in Emacs.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emulation.html

Answer (score 1):

I am also one of the Brief fans. If you feel Brief is satisfied [TsePRO](http://www.semware.com) is suited for you.

If you have some of your own Brief scripts [Crisp](http://www.crisp.com) should totally same even the script. For me I've been using [FTE](http://fte.sourceforge.net/) and I can totally configure it as Brief style even more. FTE is available both on DOS and Linux ...

Comment: Emacs really good enough which also come with [brief emulator](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/tools/brief-mode/) if configure with brief mode all power emacs feature is gone :-( the only problem I use Emacs is lisp macro I like c-like much then lisp :-W another problem is column block is working but not visual enough

Answer (score 1):

Visual SlickEdit has a Brief emulation mode -- I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CodeWright's emulation of Brief, it starts where Brief leaves off. Being a full time programmer it is well worth the cost. Try it for 30 days free.
Royce Smith

Comment: Borland killed CodeWright many years ago.

Comment: Embarcadero still sells CodeWright: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42129